# How can I combine 2 seperate MySQL queries in a foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have some posts and those posts contain comments, some posts have more than 1 comment and others have only 1 comment.

I would have to grab all the data from the user from that post and the user info from the person who commented on that post. Now say i have to echo out all that data. I would first go with a `foreach` and another `foreach` inside sorta like this!

So I made 2 MySQL queries **$postinfo** containing all userinfo for the post and the second MySQL query **$comments** containing all the comments for each post.

Now this works but I was wondering if there is a better way, better practice? The reason I want to fix this, is because I want to AJAX the comments so they can auto update and this way seems to sluggish

```
<?php
foreach ($postinfo as $info) {
    echo "<div id='container'>
              <div id='userpost'>
                  <p>" . $info['firstn'] . "</p>
                  <p>" . $info['posttext'] . "</p>
              </div>"; 
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        echo "<div id='comments'>
                  <p>' . $comment['firstn'] . '</p>
                  <p>' . $comment['commenttext'] . '</p>
              </div>"
    }
   echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

**This query is running inside the foreach to fetch the comment for a particular post.**

```
$comments = regular_query(
    "SELECT a.from_who, a.dateposted, a.topostid, a.commenttext, b.firstn
    FROM postcomments a 
    INNER JOIN users b ON a.from_who = b.id
    WHERE a.topostid = :postid",
    ["postid" => $post_idr], $conn);
```

**This one is outside the foreach:**

```
$postinfo = regular_query(
    "SELECT b.id, b.from_user, b.dateadded, b.posttype, b.posttext, b.photoname, d.firstn, d.lastn, e.status 
    FROM board b 
    INNER JOIN userprofiles c 
    INNER JOIN users d 
    INNER JOIN friendship e 
    ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
    AND b.from_user = d.id 
    AND e.friend_ids = b.from_user 
    WHERE e.status = 'Friend' 
    AND e.user_ids = :id
    ORDER BY b.id DESC",
    ["id" => (int)$user_id], $conn);
```

Comment: post some sample output

Comment: The reason this is sluggish, is because you are (probably) executing a query to to get the comments for each post separately. You can speed it up a little by getting the comments for all relevant posts in one query. After querying that information, maybe you can make `postid` the key of a multidimensional array of comments. But it's just a guess. The code snippet is unclear about what queries are executed and when, and there is no query, description of table structure and indices, and no estimation of the amount of data. Also 'seems sluggish' should rather be a concrete measurement.

Comment: is it possible to grab multiple rows pertaining to 1 row with mysql? if im fetching 40+ rows @GolezTrol

Comment: please show the SQL to get data into $userinfo & $comments

Comment: @Mikpa there i updated it

Answer (score 1):

Process One:
You can use one single query to get the one post and all its comment. But it has one problem For example One post have 20 comments so it will get post data 20 times
Query:

```
Select post.* form post  join comment on post.postId=comment.postId where post.postId='your specific post id'
```

[You may have to change the query a lil bit or there may be some typo as i don't check it on tables]

Process Two:
Have two variable one is dic another is array 
Post data will be in dictionary it will have one element with in it it will have comment array

```
       $postData={
       postId:1,
       comment:({commentId:1,comment:"bla  bla bla"},
                {commentId:2,comment:"bla  bla bla"}),
       post:"bla bla post"
       }
```

For post you have to run

```
 Select * from post where postId=your specific id
```

And for comment

```
Select * from comment where postId=your specific id
```

As simple as that

Edit:

```
for(int i=0;i<postResult.count;i++)
{
  if(i==0)
 {
    Print Your Post Info//so your post info will be echoed once
 }
    Print Your comment info//all your comment will be echoed here if any


}
```

Comment: is this mysql and what do you mean process two?

Comment: For the process 1 or 2?

Comment: Check my edited answer but you have to write it in php i have just done a demo flow. Please let me know if there are any confusion

Comment: by my understandings this for will be inside the foreach right, but say postid1 has 3 comments and postid2 has 19 comments how would i come about with your demo code?

Comment: Yes for each post entry you have to do this

Comment: nice example so would i need a foreach or just use the for loop? and if the for loop only i just need to use it once right?

Comment: with in one loop you can do it check the previous demo

Answer (score 1):

```
Select postId,postTitle,postDesc,postedBy,postedAt,
commentId,commentTitle,commentDesc,commentedBy,commentedAt 
from postTable JOIN commentTable ON postTable.postId = commentTable.postId 
WHERE postTable.postId = 1 ORDER BY commentTable.postId DESC;
```

Iterate the Data like this :

```
{posts:[
        {postId:1,postTitle:"title",postDesc:"desc",comments:[{comment1},{comment2}]},
        {postId:2,postTitle:"title",postDesc:"desc",comments:[{comment1},{comment2}]}
        {postId:3,postTitle:"title",postDesc:"desc",comments:[{comment1},{comment2}]}
    ]
}
```

Iterate the data using foreach

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    foreach($comments as $comment){

    }
}
```

Comment: if i were to use this . i would echo the layout with the outter foreach and the inner foreach would also contain an echo and there is no way you can echo a foreach with another echo.. do you get me?

Comment: yes you have to echo the layout in both the foreach...if you find it difficult...use some template engine..return the json object from the backend...and append the json object with the template engine defined...so you no need to iterate or echo the layout..

Comment: no i dont want to use jquery or ajax yet only php mysql to echo out this.

Comment: Then defined whole layout in a php variable and replace the values where you want and then echo it.for example : $html = "<div><span>POST_TITLE</span><span>POST_DESC</span></div>";
$html = str_replace("POST_TITLE",$post['postTitle'],$html) ;
$html = str_replace("POST_DESC",$post['postDesc'],$html) ;
echo $html;